# Load Runner: InvokeMethod failure: Unable to deserialize non XmlElement node #text in path 

Tags: deserialization, xml-deserialization

I passing the following to LoadRunner:

```
<makeAtmPayment xmlns=\"http://[URL]" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">"
 "<billerId>BILL01</billerId>" 
 "<userId>950002</userId>" 
 "<productCode>P1</productCode>" 
 "<productParameter><value>923</value></productParameter>"
 "<paymentChannel>PAY01</paymentChannel>"
 "<paymentAmount>2</paymentAmount>"
 "<convenienceFee>1.50</convenienceFee>" 
 "<effectiveDate>2011-04-14</effectiveDate>" 
 "<accountId xsi:nil=\"true\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"/>"
 "<atmCardNumber>564373636363636</atmCardNumber>" 
 "<editedConfirmationId xsi:nil=\"true\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"/>"
"</makeAtmPayment>"
```

and it's throwing me the following error:

`InvokeMethod failure: Unable to deserialize non XmlElement node #text in path '/makeAtmPayment/productParameter/name/#text'.`

Can anyone give me any pointers on what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
<productParameter><value>923</value></productParameter>
```

To

```
<productParameter><name>923</name></productParameter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the double quotes. There is one missing at the very beginning and there is one without a slash after xmlns=\"http://[URL]". Could it be the problem?

Comment: That was a typo from me, thats not the issue... :(

Answer (score 0):

Is this an XML of your own creation or one picked up off of a loadrunner recording?   If it is the latter consider recording twice to see what differences get picked up that you need to accommodate during your development.  If it is the former, then consider validating your XML through the application's business rules before submitting it via LoadRunner, just to ensure that the XML is sound independent of your testing tool